# Imported library not recognized in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm have a problem importing a library. I first tried importing it as an external library, which leads to this:
[image]

...afterwards, I searched StackOverflow, created a folder named /libs, and copied the JAR there, but it still doesn't work:
[image]

Any pointers?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to add the external library (`TSim.jar`) to the build path of your project. A `.jar` just being in the project folder does not automatically make it part of the class path.

Right click on project name => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries tab => Add JARs... => and select your TSim.jar

You might need to do a Clean/Rebuild after this.

Comment: Does `TSim.jar` contain the package `TSim` and classes like `TSimInterface`? It looks it doesn't.

Comment: It contains TSimInterface.class. The file just contains a bunch of class files. I can't see any package names / folders except META-INF.

Comment: Ah.. The error is "declared packaged "" doesn't match expected package TSim". Do I now just have to make a folder /TSim and put the class files in there?

Comment: In your source you refer to `TSim.TSimInteface` class/interface which means your `TSim.jar` must contain a file named `TSim/TSimInterface.class`. Can you find that?

Comment: If `TSim.jar` cointains your referred classes just not in the `TSim` folder, then you import the wrong (or non-existing) package. Correct it in your `import` statement. If classes are not in any folder, then they are part of the default package in which case you don't need to use an `import` statement for them (just ensure the jar is on the class path).

Comment: Ok, this fixed it. Thanks! The JAR was missing a folder /TSim. That file was originally created in 2005. I guess there have been a few changes in Java since then...

Answer (score 0):

first clean the project.Follow the steps

1. go to project tab
2. click clean
3. select your project and clean

next add the jar.Follow the steps

1. right click on project
2. click buildpath->configure buildpath
3. click the libraries tab
4. click on add external jars and give the path of the jar

Comment: @twy009987 are you sure that you are using the right jar.Check if the tsim.jar contains commandexception or not

Comment: @twy009987 undo all what have you done before(like the way you added jar in different folder etc etc) and follow as per my answer.If it still did not solve then create a new project and try as per my answer